# iOS Simulator cannot create devices after upgrading to Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-simulator

I just recently upgraded to XCode 6.1.1 from 5.1.1.  When I launch iOS Simulator.  I get an error "Unable to boot device in current state: Creating".  I have tried deleting the devices and adding them back manually.  But that is to no avail.  I have reinstalled XCode as well after uninstalling and cleaning my Library and Preferences folders.  That also has not worked.  I am not sure if there are artifacts left over from 5.1.1 that are causing this.

Does anyone know what the root cause/solution is?

Please Advise

Answer (score 3):

This error can happen if you renamed Xcode.app.  I suggest you do the following:

1. Quit Xcode.app, iOS Simulator.app, etc.
2. Execute: sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
3. Execute: rm -rf ~/Library/*/CoreSimulator
4. Reboot and try again.

Answer (score 0):

What do you find when you go to XCode > Preferences > Downloads?

You may need to update the simulators within this preference.[image: xcode downloads]